# check format of date from streaming file python

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, date, datetime

I have a large data frame. One of the columns is a date in the format (mmddyear). It has to follow this format. I can't have any dash lines (i.e. mm-dd-year) in between.

What is the most efficient way to get python to filter out all the data with the wrong formatted year from a large dataset?

For instance, I have this data frame:

```
sales = [('account', ['A11', 'C11',  'A12','B12','A13','B11','C12','C13']),
     ('date', [1011997,  7202005,2011997,12102001,10012000,11012001,'','110'])
     ]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_items(sales)
```

which ouptputs:

```
account date
0   A11 1011997
1   C11 7202005
2   A12 2011997
3   B12 12102001
4   A13 10012000
5   B11 11012001
6   C12 
7   C13 110
```

The date format for C12 and C13 are wrong.

Comment: Filter them to what exactly?

Comment: By filter, I mean remove an line that doesn't have the write account format. In the case above, I want to remove the last two lines

Answer (score 0):

To filter the dates themselves you should first check to make sure that the length of the value is right and then verify that it's a valid date.

```
from datetime import datetime

def check_date(date):
    date = str(date)
    length = len(date)

    # Date string is 8 characters, except for Jan. - Sept.
    if length != 7 and length != 8:
        return False

    if length == 7:
        date = "0" + date

    # Check if the date string is valid
    try:
        datetime(year=int(date[4:]), month=int(date[0:2]), day=int(date[2:4]))
    except:
        return False

    return True
```

Comment: Hi, I keep getting false for all the inputs. For example, I tried check_date('20180101'), check_date('20170101'),check_date('20012007') and I got false for all of them when I expected to return true for the first two at least. Am I calling the function wrong?

Comment: In your original post you said the date formats were in MMDDYYYY but it looks like you're testing it with YYYYDDMM. Edit: I made a small change to the function as well

Comment: Thanks. When I enter the date 1122017 (mmddyyyy) I get 11012017 when I should get 01122017. Could there still be a bug in the code?

Answer (score 0):

Since your date format is a valid integer, it is probably easiest to test for valid dates directly from the integer value like:

#### Code:

```
def valid_date(date):
    if not isinstance(date, int):
        try:
            date = int(date)
        except ValueError:
            return False

    month_day, year = divmod(date, 10000)
    month, day = divmod(month_day, 100)

    try:
        dt.datetime(year=year, month=month, day=day)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

#### Drop Rows:

```
df[df.date.apply(valid_date)]
```

#### Test Code:

```
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd

sales = [
    ('account', ['A11', 'C11', 'A12', 'B12', 'A13', 'B11', 'C12', 'C13']),
    ('date',
     [1011997, 7202005, 2011997, 12102001, 10012000, 11012001, '', '110'])
    ]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_items(sales)

print(df)
   
print(df[df.date.apply(valid_date)])
```

#### Results:

```
  account      date
0     A11   1011997
1     C11   7202005
2     A12   2011997
3     B12  12102001
4     A13  10012000
5     B11  11012001
6     C12          
7     C13       110

  account      date
0     A11   1011997
1     C11   7202005
2     A12   2011997
3     B12  12102001
4     A13  10012000
5     B11  11012001
```

Comment: Thanks. When I apply the code to a data frame,   the date 1122017 (mmddyyyy) outputs 11012017 when I should get 01122017. The code pads the day dd with zero in stead of the month mm. Is there to fix this?